# Convert 7 lines after match to CSV rows using awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
707.421
KFDTL902
C
107.31 NL
Chn PCO
FMN 
Chn Co
727.102
KFDTL901
C
107.32 NL
Chn PCO
FMN 
Chn Co
```

It repeats in this pattern. 
I am attempting to match against the 707.xxx ([0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}), and take the next 7 lines after the match, and make them rows of a CSV with the first cell being the regex match. So the output would be:

```
707.421,KFDTL902,C,107.31 NL,Chn PCO,FMN,Chn Co
707.421,KFDTL902,C,107.31 NL,Chn PCO,FMN,Chn Co
707.421,KFDTL902,C,107.31 NL,Chn PCO,FMN,Chn Co
```

Is it possible to do this using awk or sed? How can I use the next 7 lines after a match using these tools?

Comment: Why are there three repeated lines in the output? And 707.xxx would be `707.[0-9]{3}`, right?

Comment: Please add an example that is consistent with your output. Do you want to match against `707` followed by `.` followed by three characters or against `[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}`?

Comment: Are the blocks always `regex`+6 lines or can thee be more than 6 lines before the next match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^[0-9]\{3\}\.[0-9]\{3\}$/{N;N;N;N;N;N;s/\n/,/g}' input.txt
707.421,KFDTL902,C,107.31 NL,Chn PCO,FMN ,Chn Co
727.102,KFDTL901,C,107.32 NL,Chn PCO,FMN ,Chn Co
```

For each line matching the pattern, read and append the next 6 lines to the pattern space, then replace all newlines with commas.